# Should I use Url.Content() or ResolveUrl() in my MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-rewriting, .net-4.0, relative-path

When building code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/js.js")%>"></script>
```

or

```
<input type="image" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/img/submit.png")%>" />
```

Should I use `Url.Content` or `ResolveUrl()`? What's the difference?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using IIS URL Rewriting within your MVC application, e.g. internally treating http://yoursubdomain.example.com/MyController/MyAction as http://hosted.example.com/yoursubdomain/MyController/MyAction, Url.Content() will generate a correct subdomain-relative link.  ResolveUrl() will generate an incorrect link in this situation.

Answer (score 14):

`Url.Content` is more MVCish as it is the normal. [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) has been around since the beginning of ASP.NET.

Comment: @Darin Any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: In an MVC application I would prefer `Url.Content`. It's kind of more unit-testable friendly.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to capture site root into local variable and reuse it

```
<% var siteroot = Url.Content("~/") %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: siteroot %>Script/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: siteroot %>Script/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

It should save a few ms :)

Comment: This probably saves less than a few milliseconds.

Comment: I don't think it's saving anything. It makes more sense to package your JS and CSS up using Gulp than micromanaging urls.