# how to use resolve url in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can any body help me to resolve url (route url) in MVC

when i enter into the system it redirects me to Dashboard it works perfectly.

I have user defined menu whose routing value stored in database as follows
suppose i entered into the system it will redirect me to Dashboard page 
suppose i want to redirect to usermaster page then url should be as follows
http://localhost:6782/Home/Index

but when i try to redirect to home index page the url should look like this
http://localhost:6782/Dashboard/~/Voucher/Create

i want to remove Dashboard/~ 
how plz let me know

Comment: hi @vaibhav please use @Href("~/Voucher/Create") or use @URL.Action()

Comment: url created dynamically is as follow                                                                                       strMenu = strMenu + "<li><a href='" + subItem.vUrl + "'>" + subItem.vDescription + " </a>";                                                                                I tried @URL.Action() but its not working so please help me

Comment: strMenu = strMenu + "<li><a href='@Href("~/"+subItem.vUrl)'>" + subItem.vDescription + " </a>"; i hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried this but it shows me http://localhost:6782/Dashboard/@Href('~/''Voucher/Create' Dashboard is not getting resolve

Comment: Please tell me, which render engine you are using razor or aspx mvc and where you generating url in controller or view ?

Comment: Lets see you code to do the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider about @Url.Content("~\Action\").

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS URL Rewriting within your MVC application, e.g. internally treating http://yoursubdomain.example.com/MyController/MyAction as http://hosted.example.com/yoursubdomain/MyController/MyAction, Url.Content() will generate a correct subdomain-relative link. ResolveUrl() will generate an incorrect link in this situation.

Source:[Should I use Url.Content() or ResolveUrl() in my MVC views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418050/should-i-use-url-content-or-resolveurl-in-my-mvc-views)

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the URL in the database as the URL may change according to the routing rules.

Try to store the controller name and action name in the database and in your code that builds the menu use @Url.Action and pass the controller and action retrieved from the database